# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] appends dot to the end of URL

Tags: php

I am calling a function that reads `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and render an anchor element with href that is read from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

On my mobile theme on Android devices this function appends a dot at the end of the url, so it looks like www.example.com. which makes some other functions work improperly.

Upon debugging I realized that it is precisely `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` that has this wrong value.

Anyone has this problem or any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You need to post your full code. I suspect misuse of concatenates. Plus, anchors are ditched by Facebook if you ever were to try and share something specific.

Comment: 1. PHP works the same way no matter what kind of device make an request. 2. I don't think it's possible. 3. Show accurate code sample.

Comment: The [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) command might help you: `$host = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.');`

Comment: Show the code, otherwise you'll never get a real answer.

Comment: Show piece of line where you are using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: If server was `www.example.com` and you are only using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` then that would only show as `www.example.com` - If you are not using `http://` in front of that, your link may give you problems. You need to use `$server = "http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` thus resulting in `http://www.example.com` and you may have a `dot` after that with another directive that is invalid therefore resulting in a trailing un-used dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think its php issue, but this code can resolve your issue.

```
trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Domain Name System, and most notably, in DNS zone files, a fully qualified domain name is specified with a trailing dot. For example,
somehost.example.com. specifies an absolute domain name that ends with an empty top level domain label.

So the PHP is actually returning the correct value. As to how to combat this, use sudhakar's suggestion.